# VB6 Data Reports do not match datasource using ADO Shape

Tags: vb6, report, ado

I'm trying to get the datareport working since dataflexgrid is already working, although I'm having a hard time passing the values to datareport, I can't even pass one please help thanks.

PS. all of them are in one form

```
Set mRS = New ADODB.Recordset
mRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
mRS.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
mRS.LockType = adLockReadOnly

If mRS.State = 1 Then mRS.Close

mRS.Open "SHAPE {" & _
        "SELECT " & _
        "space(memberstree.level*6) + customer.description, " & _
        "customer.customercode, " & _
        "customer.remarks, " & _
        "customer.membersince " & _
    "From CUSTOMER " & _
        "INNER JOIN memberstree on customer.customercode = memberstree.customercode " & xRootNode & " " & _
        "ORDER by memberstree.pedigree + ltrim(str(memberstree.node,6,0))} AS rsCustomer " & _
        "APPEND (( SHAPE {SELECT transactionNo, logdate, customercode, GrandTotal " & _
    "From FinishedTransaction where " & xCriteria & "} AS rsTransaction " & _
        "APPEND ({SELECT TransactionNo, Description, Qty From FinishedSales} As rsSales " & _
        "RELATE TransactionNo TO TransactionNo))" & _
        " RELATE customercode TO customercode)", gCNMark
 mRS.Requery

Set MSHFlexGrid1.DataSource = mRS
```

I think this is the code that isn't working

```
With rptShape
Set .DataSource = mRS
.DataMember = ""


    With .Sections("FinishedSales_Detail").Controls
    .Item("txtDescription").DataMember = "rsSales"
    .Item("txtDescription").DataField = "Description"
    End With
```

.Show 1

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now I have 3 TABLE with 2 SHAPE Command but in the data report I have 3 Group Header and supposed to be 2 as well.